# Google+ Share Stopped working

Tags: android, google-plus

I have an android app and I'm implementing share following [these](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) instructions.

I manage to get it working. I came back to it the next day and I get this output in logcat:

```
 G+ on connection failed ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{422d8470: android.os.BinderProxy@422d8410}}
```

I have triple checked the api console, removed my OAuth clientID and input again fresh.  This has not fixed it.  Any idea about what I can look into to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the SIGN_IN_REQUIRED connection result for a number of reasons, eg.:

- if you call `PlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();`.
- if you disconnect the app either on http://plus.google.com/apps or by calling `PlusClient.revokeAccessAndDisconnect();`.
- if your app requests authorization scopes in addition to those requested previously.

For SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, the ConnectionResult you receive contains a PendingIntent which can be used to resolve the issue. In the sample at [the instructions you're following](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started) the example code handles the error in `onConnectionFailed` with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }
    // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
    mConnectionResult = result;
}
```

`result.startResolutionForResult()` will display an account chooser or the permissions dialog to resolve the issues mentioned above, and return control to `onActivityResult`, eg:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mConnectionResult = null;
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}
```

At this point the call to `PlusClient.connect()` should succeed.

Comment: I replaced onConnectionFailed with your version and works fine now, thanks

Comment: @Lee, Correct solution,but getting a toast message "internal error occured".Have u idea about this.Thanks in advance...

Comment: @jagdish - try enabling verbose logging and see what appears in LogCat.  Run this on the command line:

    adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE

Comment: @Lee what should we set REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR to be? Thanks

Comment: @superuser REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR can be any integer constant.  Your Activity might have several points at which it starts intents for a result, all of which return to onActivityResult.  REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR helps you distinguish the intent started to resolve sign-in errors from other intents you might start.

Comment: In my case, it was failing because of there was multiple accounts registered in the device. So using result.startResolutionForResult() showed account chooser dialog. Good solution.

Comment: You just saved my life as I was going through this error for 3 days :/